# How can I take files in a P4 changelist and shelve them in a new changelist from the command line?

Tags: perforce

I start with P4 CL X, which contains only unshelved files.  I want to create CL Y, which is identical to CL X (same description, same file edits), but has those files shelved.  I'm scripting this, so it needs to be via the command line.

Problems I've run into:

1. Getting the description from one CL to another seems messy.  The best I've come up with is using p4 describe, parsing its output with regex to get just the description, and then posting it to the new one via 'p4 --field "Description=VARIABLE" change -o | p4 change -i'.  This is ugly.
2. I can shelve the files easily enough, but I can't find a command that allows me to move the shelved files over.  Alternatively, I could copy the original files over, but I don't see a way to keep them on their original CL (and I would guess that this doesn't exist as it would create a conflict in the local repo, but I am not a P4 expert).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to copy a shelf? There's a `p4 reshelve` that does exactly this.

Comment: This is promising, I'll look into it.  I didn't notice this command before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These might require tweaking for your script but they worked well enough for me in a trivial test case:

1. `p4 --field Change=new --field Files= change -o OLDCHANGE | p4 change -i`
2. `p4 unshelve -s OLDCHANGE -c NEWCHANGE ; p4 shelve -c NEWCHANGE`

Comment: I think I'm missing something.  I created an empty changelist using p4 change.  In command 1, I put in the empty CL # for NEWCHANGE, and the desired CL to be copied as OLDCHANGE (which has one file marked for add in it).

I get "Can't include file(s) not already specified. Open new files with p4 add, p4 edit, etc."

Also, is there a way to not need to create an empty CL first to provide the NEWCHANGE number?

Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Edited answer, give that a whirl.  Setting the Change field to "new" ought to just create a new changelist, and blanking the Files field forces it to be empty.

Comment: Playing around with it.  It doesn't work with files opened for add as-is, but I'm seeing if I can figure out a workaround.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it ultimately does the job for the question as stated, just not for my particular use case.  Our Perforce has some weird replication scenario so this didn't work for me.  I had to do the following instead of step 2:

2. p4 reopen - c NEWCHANGE FILENAME (repeat for each file)
p4 shelve -c NEWCHANGE
p4 reopen - c OLDCHANGE FILENAME (repeat for each file)

Not nearly as clean.